# Conda update: installation progress (version 4.3)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Doing a `conda update --all` for a Python Anaconda environment, the list of downloads is tracked one-by-one, but as soon as the installation starts, there is no visible progress anymore.

As the installation is taking quite some time - is there any option to show the installation progress?

[image]

I am using `conda --version`: `4.3.30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CHANGELOG over in the GitHub repository (https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), they had to accept some regressions on progress bar behavior that have been fixed in the (currently unreleased) conda 4.4.0.

> - various UI improvements: To push through some of the big leaps with transactions in conda 4.3, we accepted some regressions on progress bars and other user interface features. All of those indicators of progress, and more, have been brought back and further improved.

Comment: Sounds great, looking forward to it. I added the current version `4.3` to the question.